# Android Xamarin save file to windows share

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, samba, jcifs

I have a Xamarin C# project in Visual Studio 2015 to make my Android app save a file to a Windows shared folder using jCIFS.

This is the method I am using to save the file:

```
 private async Task Save2Samba(string text)
        {
            String sSambaFolder = "192.168.0.22/c";
            String url = "smb://" + sSambaFolder + "/file.txt";

            byte[] bytes = new byte[text.Length * sizeof(char)];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(text.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

            SmbFile file = null;

            NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(null, null, null);
            file = new SmbFile(url, auth);
            SmbFileOutputStream lol = new SmbFileOutputStream(file);
            lol.Write(bytes);
            lol.Flush();
            lol.Close();

        }
```

On runtime, the line where I initialize the `SmbFileOutputStream` throws a `Java.Lang.ExceptionInInitializerError` with the following error stack

```
Unhandled Exception:

Java.Lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: 

07-04 23:10:20.018 D/Mono    (22361): Image addref System.Runtime.Serialization[0xb4ab2f40] -> System.Runtime.Serialization.dll[0xb4840200]: 1
07-04 23:10:20.018 D/Mono    (22361): Assembly System.Runtime.Serialization[0xb4ab2f40] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
07-04 23:10:20.027 D/Mono    (22361): AOT module 'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/FinalInspection_Droid_Aufbau.FinalInspection_Droid_Aufbau-1/lib/arm/libaot-System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so" not found
07-04 23:10:20.036 D/Mono    (22361): AOT module '/Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-armv7/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/FinalInspection_Droid_Aufbau.FinalInspection_Droid_Aufbau-1/lib/arm/libaot-System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so" not found
07-04 23:10:20.040 D/Mono    (22361): Config attempting to parse: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.config'.
07-04 23:10:20.040 D/Mono    (22361): Config attempting to parse: '/Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-armv7/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Runtime.Serialization/System.Runtime.Serialization.config'.
07-04 23:10:20.040 D/Mono    (22361): Assembly Ref addref Mono.Android[0xb4b214c0] -> System.Runtime.Serialization[0xb4ab2f40]: 2
07-04 23:10:20.041 D/Mono    (22361): Assembly Ref addref System.Runtime.Serialization[0xb4ab2f40] -> mscorlib[0xb4ab2b80]: 17
Loaded assembly: System.Runtime.Serialization.dll [External]
07-04 23:10:23.720 D/Mono    (22361): DllImport attempting to load: '/system/lib/liblog.so'.
07-04 23:10:23.721 D/Mono    (22361): DllImport loaded library '/system/lib/liblog.so'.
07-04 23:10:23.725 D/Mono    (22361): DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/liblog.so' ('/system/lib/liblog.so').
07-04 23:10:23.725 D/Mono    (22361): Searching for '__android_log_print'.
07-04 23:10:23.725 D/Mono    (22361): Probing '__android_log_print'.
07-04 23:10:23.725 D/Mono    (22361): Found as '__android_log_print'.
07-04 23:10:23.734 I/MonoDroid(22361): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
07-04 23:10:23.743 I/MonoDroid(22361): Java.Lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.ExceptionInInitializerError' was thrown. ---> Android.OS.NetworkOnMainThreadException: Exception of type 'Android.OS.NetworkOnMainThreadException' was thrown.
07-04 23:10:23.743 I/MonoDroid(22361):   --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
07-04 23:10:23.743 I/MonoDroid(22361): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
07-04 23:10:23.743 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
07-04 23:10:23.743 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
07-04 23:10:23.743 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:396)
07-04 23:10:23.743 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at jcifs.netbios.NbtAddress.<clinit>(NbtAddress.java:187)
07-04 23:10:23.743 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at jcifs.netbios.NbtAddress.getWINSAddress(NbtAddress.java:533)
07-04 23:10:23.743 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at jcifs.UniAddress.<clinit>(UniAddress.java:62)
07-04 23:10:23.743 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.getFirstAddress(SmbFile.java:864)
07-04 23:10:23.743 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect(SmbFile.java:951)
07-04 23:10:23.743 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect0(SmbFile.java:880)
07-04 23:10:23.743 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open0(SmbFile.java:972)
07-04 23:10:23.743 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open(SmbFile.java:1006)
07-04 23:10:23.743 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream.<init>(SmbFileOutputStream.java:142)
07-04 23:10:23.743 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream.<init>(SmbFileOutputStream.java:97)
07-04 23:10:23.743 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream.<init>(SmbFileOutputStream.java:67)
07-04 23:10:23.743 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at md5ac18087b2af203d2f41df0f73b22a485.BodyInspectionForm_TabFragment.n_onOptionsItemSelected(Native Method)
07-04 23:10:23.743 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at md5ac18087b2af203d2f41df0f73b22a485.BodyInspectionForm_TabFragment.onOptionsItemSelected(BodyInspectionForm_TabFragment.java:47)
07-04 23:10:23.743 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at android.app.Fragment.performOptionsItemSelected(Fragment.java:2159)
07-04 23:10:23.743 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(FragmentManager.java:1988)
07-04 23:10:23.743 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2970)
07-04 23:10:23.743 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1136)
07-04 23:10:23.743 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:761)
07-04 23:10:23.743 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
07-04 23:10:23.743 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:904)
07-04 23:10:23.743 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:894)
07-04 23:10:23.743 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:186)
07-04 23:10:23.743 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
07-04 23:10:23.743 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1146)
07-04 23:10:23.743 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3057)
07-04 23:10:23.743 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3864)
07-04 23:10:23.744 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
07-04 23:10:23.744 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-04 23:10:23.744 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:139)
07-04 23:10:23.744 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5298)
07-04 23:10:23.744 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-04 23:10:23.744 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-04 23:10:23.744 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
07-04 23:10:23.744 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
07-04 23:10:23.744 I/MonoDroid(22361):   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
07-04 23:10:23.744 I/MonoDroid(22361):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
07-04 23:10:23.744 I/MonoDroid(22361):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+Object._NewObject (JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00085] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3340/4e275588/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.g.cs:12200 
07-04 23:10:23.744 I/MonoDroid(22361):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+Object.NewObject (JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3340/4e275588/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.Object.cs:33 
07-04 23:10:23.744 I/MonoDroid(22361):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.NewObject (IntPtr jclass, IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3340/4e275588/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:768 
07-04 23:10:23.744 I/MonoDroid(22361):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.NewObject (IntPtr jclass, IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue[] parms) [0x0001d] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3340/4e275588/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:786 
07-04 23:10:23.744 I/MonoDroid(22361):   at Jcifs.Smb.SmbFileOutputStream..ctor (Jcifs.Smb.SmbFile p0) [0x000b1] in <filename unknown>:0 
07-04 23:10:23.744 I/MonoDroid(22361):   at FinalInspection_Droid_Aufbau.BodyInspectionForm+TabFragment.Save2Samba (System.String text) [0x0004d] in E:\dlouhy\Documents\Projects\mitsenden\FinalInspection_Aufbau\Phoneword_Droid\BodyInspectionForm.cs:1527 
07-04 23:10:23.744 I/MonoDroid(22361):   at FinalInspection_Droid_Aufbau.BodyInspectionForm+TabFragment.OnOptionsItemSelected (IMenuItem item) [0x0004e] in E:\dlouhy\Documents\Projects\mitsenden\FinalInspection_Aufbau\Phoneword_Droid\BodyInspectionForm.cs:1220 
07-04 23:10:23.744 I/MonoDroid(22361):   at Android.App.Fragment.n_OnOptionsItemSelected_Landroid_view_MenuItem_ (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_item) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3340/4e275588/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-17/src/generated/Android.App.Fragment.cs:1350 
07-04 23:10:23.744 I/MonoDroid(22361):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:15133db7-418a-4549-88a0-cddc3cc27dfe (intptr,intptr,intptr)
07-04 23:10:23.744 I/MonoDroid(22361):   --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
07-04 23:10:23.744 I/MonoDroid(22361): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
07-04 23:10:23.744 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at jcifs.netbios.NbtAddress.getWINSAddress(NbtAddress.java:533)
07-04 23:10:23.744 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at jcifs.UniAddress.<clinit>(UniAddress.java:62)
07-04 23:10:23.744 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.getFirstAddress(SmbFile.java:864)
07-04 23:10:23.744 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect(SmbFile.java:951)
07-04 23:10:23.744 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect0(SmbFile.java:880)
07-04 23:10:23.744 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open0(SmbFile.java:972)
07-04 23:10:23.744 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open(SmbFile.java:1006)
07-04 23:10:23.744 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream.<init>(SmbFileOutputStream.java:142)
07-04 23:10:23.744 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream.<init>(SmbFileOutputStream.java:97)
07-04 23:10:23.744 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream.<init>(SmbFileOutputStream.java:67)
07-04 23:10:23.744 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at md5ac18087b2af203d2f41df0f73b22a485.BodyInspectionForm_TabFragment.n_onOptionsItemSelected(Native Method)
07-04 23:10:23.744 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at md5ac18087b2af203d2f41df0f73b22a485.BodyInspectionForm_TabFragment.onOptionsItemSelected(BodyInspectionForm_TabFragment.java:47)
07-04 23:10:23.744 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at android.app.Fragment.performOptionsItemSelected(Fragment.java:2159)
07-04 23:10:23.744 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(FragmentManager.java:1988)
07-04 23:10:23.744 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2970)
07-04 23:10:23.745 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1136)
07-04 23:10:23.745 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:761)
07-04 23:10:23.745 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
07-04 23:10:23.745 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:904)
07-04 23:10:23.745 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:894)
07-04 23:10:23.745 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:186)
07-04 23:10:23.745 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
07-04 23:10:23.745 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1146)
07-04 23:10:23.745 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3057)
07-04 23:10:23.745 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3864)
07-04 23:10:23.745 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
07-04 23:10:23.745 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-04 23:10:23.745 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:139)
07-04 23:10:23.745 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5298)
07-04 23:10:23.745 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-04 23:10:23.745 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-04 23:10:23.745 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
07-04 23:10:23.745 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
07-04 23:10:23.745 I/MonoDroid(22361): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
07-04 23:10:23.745 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
07-04 23:10:23.745 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
07-04 23:10:23.745 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:396)
07-04 23:10:23.745 I/MonoDroid(22361):  at jcifs.netbios.NbtAddress.<clinit>(NbtAddress.java:187)
07-04 23:10:23.745 I/MonoDroid(22361):  ... 33 more
07-04 23:10:23.758 D/Mono    (22361): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
07-04 23:10:23.758 D/Mono    (22361): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
07-04 23:10:23.758 D/Mono    (22361): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
07-04 23:10:23.759 D/Mono    (22361): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
An unhandled exception occured.

referenceTable GDEF length=670 1
referenceTable GSUB length=7202 1
referenceTable GPOS length=24560 1
referenceTable head length=54 1
referenceTable GDEF length=670 1
referenceTable GSUB length=7186 1
referenceTable GPOS length=26464 1
referenceTable head length=54 1
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361): 
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361): Unhandled Exception:
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361): Java.Lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.ExceptionInInitializerError' was thrown. ---> Android.OS.NetworkOnMainThreadException: Exception of type 'Android.OS.NetworkOnMainThreadException' was thrown.
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361): 
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:396)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at jcifs.netbios.NbtAddress.<clinit>(NbtAddress.java:187)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at jcifs.netbios.NbtAddress.getWINSAddress(NbtAddress.java:533)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at jcifs.UniAddress.<clinit>(UniAddress.java:62)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.getFirstAddress(SmbFile.java:864)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect(SmbFile.java:951)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect0(SmbFile.java:880)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open0(SmbFile.java:972)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open(SmbFile.java:1006)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream.<init>(SmbFileOutputStream.java:142)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream.<init>(SmbFileOutputStream.java:97)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream.<init>(SmbFileOutputStream.java:67)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at md5ac18087b2af203d2f41df0f73b22a485.BodyInspectionForm_TabFragment.n_onOptionsItemSelected(Native Method)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at md5ac18087b2af203d2f41df0f73b22a485.BodyInspectionForm_TabFragment.onOptionsItemSelected(BodyInspectionForm_TabFragment.java:47)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at android.app.Fragment.performOptionsItemSelected(Fragment.java:2159)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(FragmentManager.java:1988)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2970)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1136)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:761)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:904)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:894)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:186)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1146)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3057)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3864)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:139)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5298)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361): 
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+Object._NewObject (JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00085] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3340/4e275588/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.g.cs:12200 
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+Object.NewObject (JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3340/4e275588/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.Object.cs:33 
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.NewObject (IntPtr jclass, IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3340/4e275588/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:768 
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono    (22361):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.NewObject (IntPtr jclass, IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue[] parms) [0
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Java.Lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.ExceptionInInitializerError' was thrown. ---> Android.OS.NetworkOnMainThreadException: Exception of type 'Android.OS.NetworkOnMainThreadException' was thrown.
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361): 
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:396)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at jcifs.netbios.NbtAddress.<clinit>(NbtAddress.java:187)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at jcifs.netbios.NbtAddress.getWINSAddress(NbtAddress.java:533)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at jcifs.UniAddress.<clinit>(UniAddress.java:62)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.getFirstAddress(SmbFile.java:864)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect(SmbFile.java:951)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect0(SmbFile.java:880)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open0(SmbFile.java:972)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open(SmbFile.java:1006)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream.<init>(SmbFileOutputStream.java:142)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream.<init>(SmbFileOutputStream.java:97)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream.<init>(SmbFileOutputStream.java:67)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at md5ac18087b2af203d2f41df0f73b22a485.BodyInspectionForm_TabFragment.n_onOptionsItemSelected(Native Method)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at md5ac18087b2af203d2f41df0f73b22a485.BodyInspectionForm_TabFragment.onOptionsItemSelected(BodyInspectionForm_TabFragment.java:47)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at android.app.Fragment.performOptionsItemSelected(Fragment.java:2159)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(FragmentManager.java:1988)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2970)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1136)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:761)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:904)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:894)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:186)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1146)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3057)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3864)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:139)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5298)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361): 
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+Object._NewObject (JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00085] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3340/4e275588/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.g.cs:12200 
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+Object.NewObject (JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3340/4e275588/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.Object.cs:33 
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.NewObject (IntPtr jclass, IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3340/4e275588/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:768 
07-04 23:10:24.571 E/mono-rt (22361):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.NewObject (IntPtr jclass, IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JV
```

I added these permissions to my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Can anyone help me with this?

**Edit:**
Updated the code snippet according to the comment.

Comment: to start with, you are using 127.0.0.1, which is the loopback address.  You need to use the IP or FQDN of the machine that you want to connect to

Answer (score 2):

Change your:

```
"127.0.0.1/Desktop-l8s2bi3/c"
```

To the IP address or host name of your Samba share server:

```
"MyWindowsPCDesktop/Desktop-l8s2bi3/c"
```

As "127.0.0.1" would be referencing the Android device/emulator itself.

Re: https://github.com/sushihangover/Xamarin.Android.jCIFS

```
// This is NOT best-practice code, just showing a demo Jcifs api call
public async Task getFileContents ()
{
    await Task.Run (() => {
        var smbStream = new SmbFileInputStream ("smb://guest@10.10.10.5/code/test.txt");
        byte[] b = new byte[8192];
        int n;
        while ((n = smbStream.Read (b)) > 0) {
            Console.Write (Encoding.UTF8.GetString (b).ToCharArray (), 0, n);
        }
        Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);
        RunOnUiThread(() => {
            button.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString (b);
        });
    }
    ).ContinueWith ((Task arg) => {
        Console.WriteLine (arg.Status);
        if (arg.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted)
            Console.WriteLine (arg.Exception);
    }
    );
}
```

Comment: I changed the sSambafolder to "IP/Folder". I added `async` changed the return type to `Task` and now when the app should execute the `new SmbFileOutputStrem` it just jumps out of the method and continues to execute the code after the Samba2Save method .. I have no idea what is happening

Comment: To try the API I inserted the `getFileContents`code in my application. When I execute the code, nothing happens and when debugging through it, Visual Studio opens a Find Source Dialog and looks for `XAPeerMembers.cs`..