# How to Save Photos to shared folder in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I tried lots of codes to save aphoto to a shared folder. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57752466/how-to-save-photos-from-gallery-to-shared-folder-on-a-windows-server-in-xamarin) question is very similar, so I tried to addapt it to my code but I'm having always the same error:

> SharpCifs.Smb.SmbException: Failed to connect to server

> SharpCifs.Smb.SmbException: Invalid operation for workgroups, servers, or shares  at SharpCifs.Smb.SmbFile.CreateNewFile () [

I tried using the name of the shared folder or even the IP, but i have the same error. I checked the domain, username and password to be Ok and yes they are. The error happens in line  `dest.CreateNewFile(); //Here I have the error`

I'm using C# on Windows Visual Studio 2022

Practically is the same code so I don't know and can´t find a solution:

```
    private async void TakePhoto_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string photoSavePath = "folderPath";
        byte[] imageToByte;

        try
        {
            var photo = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(
            new StoreCameraMediaOptions
            {
                    SaveToAlbum = true
            });

            imageToByte = FileToByteArray(photo);

            var windowsAuth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("domain", "username", "password");
                                  
            var dest = new SmbFile(photoSavePath + photoName, windowsAuth);

            dest.CreateNewFile(); //Here I have the error
            var writeStream = dest.GetOutputStream();
            writeStream.Write(imageToByte);
            writeStream.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.InnerException.Message);
        }           
    }

 private byte[] FileToByteArray(MediaFile photo)
    {
        ImageSource imageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
        {
                var stream = photo.GetStream();
                photo.Dispose();
                return stream;
        });

        //Convert ImatgeStream to BYTE[]
        var imageToByte = ConvertMediaFileToByteArray(photo);


        return imageToByte;
    }

    private byte[] ConvertMediaFileToByteArray(MediaFile file)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            file.GetStream().CopyTo(memoryStream);
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you verified that your device can connect to the server?  Have you verified your firewall isn't blocking any ports?  Have you tried using some third party CIFS app on your device to verify that it can connect?

Comment: The device can connect to the server and the firewall is not blocking any ports. I will check for the third partys CIFS app on my device. I really don't know how to do it but I'll search.

Comment: You can check [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38192371/android-xamarin-save-file-to-windows-share) which tries to save the file to shared folder in the xamarin.android.