# Connect to shared folder in windows domain with .net MAUI c#

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I'm very new to .net Maui (and android altogether) and I'm trying out some stuff.

I'm trying to create an app that runs on an android phone. The goal of the app is that the user fills in some data and then takes a picture. Once the picture is approved by the user, the app needs to be able to create a folder (depending on the user data) on a shared folder in a windows domain and save the picture to this folder.
The user is connected to a wifi accespoint in the same network of the domain (no need to connect from outside the network).

I was able to do all of the above, but I was only able to save the picture locally so it can be seen in the google photos app. I cannot seem to figure out the part to save the file to a shared folder in the network.

I tried the code from this post: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-access-network-drive-using-c-sharp ,and it works when the app is running on a windows machine, but when I try the same code on an android device I get the error "mpr.dll is missing".

I also tried the code from this post: [Android Xamarin save file to windows share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38192371/android-xamarin-save-file-to-windows-share) but was not able to make it work. My post was originally indicated as a duplicate from this post, but the post was originaly made in 2016 and did not have a valid answer. I would like to think that after 7 years in this rapid evolving technology there are new and better ways do do what I want?

Does anyone know how to do this the right way on an android device via a .net Maui app?

Thanks!

Comment: The suggested answer is very old and refer to a solution using SMB 1.0, which is the oldest Microsoft network protocol. Nowaday SMB 2.0, 2.1 and 3.0 exists, with the former required on Windows 10 and above. So probably you need a newer library, maybe something like this https://github.com/YoshiroTamura/SMB2forXamarinForms